# Cannot read property of undefined - D3 hive plot

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js, data-visualization

I've been trying to create a hive plot for a protein interaction data. When I run this code (Work in Progress), there's no hive plot; Also, the web inspector shows an error: "cannot read property 'type' of undefined."

*When I change the code to nodes.type, nodes.position, links.SourceNode.type in the draw links portion, it throws a weird error, along with the previous error:

Error: Invalid value for  attribute d="MNaN,NaNCNaN,NaN NaN,NaN NaN,NaN" samplehiveplot.html:1
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined *

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style>
  .axis {
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width:1.5px;
  }

  .node {
    stroke:#000;
  }

  .link {
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
    stroke-opacity: 0.8;
  }

  .link.turnedOn {
    stroke-width: 3px;
  }

  .link.turnedOff {
    stroke-opacity: 0.3;
    stroke-width: 1px;
  }

  .node.turnedOn {
    stroke: red;
    stroke-width: 3px;
  }
</style>

<body>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.hive.v0.min.js"></script>


<script>

var width = 1000,
    height = 1000,
    innerRadius = 20,
    outerRadius = 240;

var angle = d3.scale.ordinal()
              .domain(d3.range(4))
              .rangePoints([0, 2 * Math.PI]),
    radius = d3.scale.linear()
              .range([innerRadius, outerRadius]),
    color = d3.scale.category10()
              .domain(d3.range(20));

   
     
var nodes = [{"number":1,"type":0,"position":0.1,"name":"TFC3","group":"yal001c"},
{"number":2,"type":2,"position":0.1003,"name":"SSA1","group":"yal005c"},
{"number":3,"type":2,"position":0.1006,"name":"TPD3","group":"yal016w"},
{"number":4,"type":2,"position":0.1009,"name":"CCR4","group":"yal021c"},
{"number":5,"type":2,"position":0.1012,"name":"PMT2","group":"yal023c"},
{"number":6,"type":2,"position":0.1015,"name":"LTE1","group":"yal024c"},
{"number":7,"type":2,"position":0.1018,"name":"YAL028W","group":"yal028w"},
{"number":8,"type":2,"position":0.1021,"name":"MYO4","group":"yal029c"},
{"number":9,"type":2,"position":0.1024,"name":"SNC1","group":"yal030w"},
{"number":10,"type":1,"position":0.1027,"name":"FUN20","group":"yal032c"},
{"number":11,"type":0,"position":0.103,"name":"YAL034W-A","group":"yal034w-a"}
];

var links = [
{"SourceNode": nodes[1], "TargetNode": nodes[35]},
{"SourceNode": nodes[1], "TargetNode": nodes[856]},
{"SourceNode": nodes[1], "TargetNode": nodes[1647]},
{"SourceNode": nodes[1], "TargetNode": nodes[2009]},
{"SourceNode": nodes[1], "TargetNode": nodes[2024]},
{"SourceNode": nodes[2],"TargetNode": nodes[234]},
{"SourceNode": nodes[2],"TargetNode": nodes[1376]},
{"SourceNode": nodes[2],"TargetNode": nodes[1488]},
{"SourceNode": nodes[3],"TargetNode": nodes[671]}
];

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/2 + "," + height/2 + ")");

svg.selectAll(".axis")
    .data(d3.range(3))
  .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + degrees(angle(d)) + ")" })
    .attr("x1", radius.range()[0])
    .attr("x2", radius.range()[1]);

// draw links
svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(links)
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", d3.hive.link()
      .angle(function(d) { return angle(d.type); })
      .radius(function(d) { return radius(d.position); }))
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.SourceNode.type); })
    .on("mouseover", linkMouseover)
    .on("mouseout", mouseout);

// draw nodes
svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + degrees(angle(d.type)) + ")"; })
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return radius(d.position); })
    .attr("r", 5)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.type); })
    .on("mouseover", nodeMouseover)
    .on("mouseout", mouseout);

// highlight link and connected nodes on mouseover
function linkMouseover(d) {
  svg.selectAll(".link")
    .classed("turnedOn", function(dl) {
      return dl === d;
    })
    .classed("turnedOff", function(dl) {
      return !(dl === d);
    })
  svg.selectAll(".node")
    .classed("turnedOn", function(dl) {
      return dl === d.SourceNode || dl === d.TargetNode;
    })
}

// highlight node and connected links on mouseover
function nodeMouseover(d) {
  svg.selectAll(".link")
    .classed("turnedOn", function(dl) {
      return dl.SourceNode === d || dl.TargetNode === d;
    })
    .classed("turnedOff", function(dl) {
      return !(dl.SourceNode === d || dl.TargetNode === d)
    });
  d3.select(this)
    .classed("turnedOn", true);
}

// clear highlighted nodes or links
function mouseout() {
  svg.selectAll(".turnedOn").classed("turnedOn", false);
  svg.selectAll(".turnedOff").classed("turnedOff", false);
}

function degrees(radians) {
  return radians / Math.PI * 180 - 90;
}



</script>
```

Any idea why?? I've tried looking at other similar questions but couldn't get an answer from them. I am using a chrome browser (latest version). And this code is a modified version from this: http://bl.ocks.org/officeofjane/ad5204f200a830acc8dc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your input `links`. First of all, `links` should be an `Array` of `Objects`, where each `Object` has a `"source"` and `"target"` field (as opposed to `"sourceNode"` and `"targetNode"`). Next, your links are defined by indexing into the `nodes` `Array`, but many of your indices are way greater than the length of the nodes, causing additional problems. I'm not sure what you're trying to do there, but if you change `links` as follows:

```
var links = [
{source: nodes[1], target: nodes[3]},
{source: nodes[1], target: nodes[4]},
{source: nodes[1], target: nodes[5]},
{source: nodes[1], target: nodes[6]},
{source: nodes[1], target: nodes[7]},
{source: nodes[2],target: nodes[3]},
{source: nodes[2],target: nodes[4]},
{source: nodes[2],target: nodes[5]},
{source: nodes[3],target: nodes[6]}
];
```

and change your references to `d.sourceNode` to `d.source` and `d.targetNode` to `d.target`, you will get output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Changing SourceNode and TargetNode to source and target worked. The data has a total of 2114 nodes; I've just not mentioned all of them in the snippet, because of space issues. Sorry if that caused any confusion. I thought I had mentioned it in the beginning.

Comment: @Minu: ah makes sense. If you feel my answer has solved your problem, you can [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). And sure I'll take a look at your other question.